# Will three.js Object3D.clone() create a deep copy of the geometry?

Tags: three.js

I'm loading models using the collada loader. The loader returns an Object3D, "dae", with many child meshes. I'd like to instantiate the parent "dae" object many times without duplicating the meshes. Can I just use dae.clone()?

Put another way: I'd like to make shallow copies that all have their own transformation matrix but share the same geometry. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: The source is openly available, why not look? Or you could create a test or two and try it out.

Answer (score 7):

By default `Object3D.clone()` does create a deep copy. Let's take a look at the [source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L509)

```js
clone: function ( object, recursive ) {

    if ( object === undefined ) object = new THREE.Object3D();
    if ( recursive === undefined ) recursive = true;

    object.name = this.name;

    object.up.copy( this.up );

    object.position.copy( this.position );
    object.quaternion.copy( this.quaternion );
    object.scale.copy( this.scale );

    object.renderDepth = this.renderDepth;

    object.rotationAutoUpdate = this.rotationAutoUpdate;

    object.matrix.copy( this.matrix );
    object.matrixWorld.copy( this.matrixWorld );

    object.matrixAutoUpdate = this.matrixAutoUpdate;
    object.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = this.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate;

    object.visible = this.visible;

    object.castShadow = this.castShadow;
    object.receiveShadow = this.receiveShadow;

    object.frustumCulled = this.frustumCulled;

    object.userData = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( this.userData ) );

    if ( recursive === true ) {

        for ( var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i ++ ) {

            var child = this.children[ i ];
            object.add( child.clone() );

        }

    }

    return object;

}
```

As we can see the `clone` function accepts two optional arguments:

1. the object to clone  the `Object3D` into.
2. a flag to indicate whether or not to recursively clone the children.

So yes it is possible to make shallow copies with respect to the `Object3D.children`, but that's not what you want (based on your comment).

I believe you can actually use the default behavior of `Object3D.clone()` to get what you are after. `Mesh.clone()` does not clone the `Geometry` and `Material` properties.

```js
THREE.Mesh.prototype.clone = function ( object ) {

    if ( object === undefined ) object = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );

    THREE.Object3D.prototype.clone.call( this, object );

    return object;

};
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that and the flag. However I'm still not entirely sure this is the answer I'm looking for. Children are Object3Ds. I do want to copy those. I just don't want to copy the meshes. Meshes should be shared by all instances, while the object hierarchy should stay intact.

Comment: Clone does not take any argument at this moment (Three.js release 73) [clone line here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L716)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a couple of function I use to clone object's materials deeply. You could modify this to your needs

Also consider this information : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5754

```
    /** Gives the aptitude for an object3D to clone recursively with its material cloned (normal clone does not clone material)*/

    THREE.Object3D.prototype.GdeepCloneMaterials = function() {
        var object = this.clone( new THREE.Object3D(), false );

        for ( var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++ ) {

            var child = this.children[ i ];
            if ( child.GdeepCloneMaterials ) {
                object.add( child.GdeepCloneMaterials() );
            } else {
                object.add( child.clone() );
            }

        }
        return object;
    };

    THREE.Mesh.prototype.GdeepCloneMaterials = function( object, recursive ) {
        if ( object === undefined ) {
            object = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material.clone() );
        }

        THREE.Object3D.prototype.GdeepCloneMaterials.call( this, object, recursive );

        return object;
    };
```

Comment: @michael-p how do you use this? replacing `object.clone()` with `object.GdeepCloneMaterials()` will never call `mesh.GdeepCloneMaterials()`

Comment: Mesh is a subclass of Object3D, thus it will

Comment: Mesh creation fails if `this.material` is an Array.
It works with the following changes:
```
 if ( object === undefined ) {
  if(Array.isArray(this.material)){
   let materials = [];
   this.material.forEach( material => {
    materials.push( material.clone() );
   });
   object = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, materials );
  } else {
   object = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material.clone() );
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the `copy`and `clone` methods in `Object3D` to deep clone mesh materials.

First,extends two new methods in THREE:

```
THREE.Object3D.prototype.deepClone = function ( recursive ) {

    return new this.constructor().deepCopy( this, recursive );

},
THREE.Object3D.prototype.deepCopy = function( source, recursive ) {

        if ( recursive === undefined ) recursive = true;

        this.name = source.name;

        this.up.copy( source.up );

        this.position.copy( source.position );
        this.quaternion.copy( source.quaternion );
        this.scale.copy( source.scale );

        this.matrix.copy( source.matrix );
        this.matrixWorld.copy( source.matrixWorld );
        if(source.material){
            //changed
            this.material = source.material.clone()
        }
        if(source.geometry){
            //changed
            this.geometry = source.geometry.clone()
        }
        this.matrixAutoUpdate = source.matrixAutoUpdate;
        this.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = source.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate;

        this.layers.mask = source.layers.mask;
        this.visible = source.visible;

        this.castShadow = source.castShadow;
        this.receiveShadow = source.receiveShadow;

        this.frustumCulled = source.frustumCulled;
        this.renderOrder = source.renderOrder;

        this.userData = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( source.userData ) );

        if ( recursive === true ) {

            for ( var i = 0; i < source.children.length; i ++ ) {

                var child = source.children[ i ];
                this.add( child.deepClone() ); //changed

            }

        }

        return this;

    }
```

Second,when you want to deep clone a Object3D or Scene named `originalObj`.just do `var newObj = originalObj.deepClone()`

Answer (score 2):

three.js `Object3D.clone()` will **not** create a deep copy of geometry and material. It will reference geometry and material of the cloned object instead.

You can see this in *three.module.js*:

```
Mesh.prototype = ... {

    ...,

    copy: function ( source ) {
        Object3D.prototype.copy.call( this, source );

        ...

>>>>>>> this.material = source.material; <<<<<<<
>>>>>>> this.geometry = source.geometry; <<<<<<<

        return this;

    }

    ...

}
```

So, regarding the OP's question: Yes, you can just use `dae.clone()`.

For a **deep clone including geometry and material**, just change two lines of the above `Mesh.prototype.copy()` function:

```
this.material = source.material.clone();
this.geometry = source.geometry.clone();
```

Keep in mind this is a performance issue because three.js has to calculate separate geometries for each object3D, including all Meshes.

Answer (score 0):

Each THREE.Mesh can have only a single parent, so if you want the mesh to be rendered multiple places in the scene graph, you must clone the meshes. This means you need to use `.clone()`, which is a deep clone as far as the scene graph is concerned.

The method does *not* duplicate the `mesh.geometry` or `mesh.material` properties however – those are the expensive resources in this situation, and they are reused automatically.

*Updated as of three.js r155.*