# Three.js clone creates a copy of mesh information of the volume and its childs

Tags: json, three.js, clone

I need to create a 3D model of a complex geometry (nuclear physics particle detectors) using ThreeJS.
In one example I have about 100.000 geometries and 4.5 Million logical volumes.
I import the geometry using JSON format but then I'm facing two problems.

1. the JSON file is huge (3.5 Gb)
2. obviously the file cannot be imported using the editor available at http://threejs.org/editor/. Probably because of memory problems.

For example, in the JSON file I'm using a new UUID when I position a volume. I'm woundering if I could use the UID of the volume that I have already positioned once whithout redefining all of its childs and this should be enough to reposition the full tree.

Just for clarification I create a small example of JSON file where "Box 1" contains others volumes and then I cloned "Box 1" and repositioned it inside "Container 1". You can see that that all childs of "Box 1" have also been copied (indeed only information about mesh.

```
{
"metadata": {
    "version": 4.3,
    "type": "Object",
    "generator": "ObjectExporter"
},
"geometries": [
    {
        "uuid": "0F1A7764-83AC-41AE-BB49-AE74A475CF80",
        "type": "BoxGeometry",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500,
        "depth": 500,
        "widthSegments": 1,
        "heightSegments": 1,
        "depthSegments": 1
    },
    {
        "uuid": "E69365CA-206A-4286-BB0D-940A804B7DEB",
        "type": "TorusGeometry",
        "radius": 100,
        "tube": 40,
        "radialSegments": 16,
        "tubularSegments": 64,
        "arc": 6.28
    },
    {
        "uuid": "B2B3E2FD-17C5-42B3-8732-0918F4196199",
        "type": "SphereGeometry",
        "radius": 75,
        "widthSegments": 32,
        "heightSegments": 16,
        "phiStart": 0,
        "phiLength": 6.283185307179586,
        "thetaStart": 0,
        "thetaLength": 3.141592653589793
    },
    {
        "uuid": "CCB3F065-632D-4AD4-AB16-6DC65D3F9163",
        "type": "CylinderGeometry",
        "radiusTop": 20,
        "radiusBottom": 20,
        "height": 100,
        "radialSegments": 32,
        "heightSegments": 1,
        "openEnded": false
    },
    {
        "uuid": "D3905F27-8D63-447B-A4D2-D4901FAB00E2",
        "type": "BoxGeometry",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "depth": 100,
        "widthSegments": 1,
        "heightSegments": 1,
        "depthSegments": 1
    },
    {
        "uuid": "EE1DB156-C18F-41B1-B1B5-E4B2619F6FC2",
        "type": "BoxGeometry",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "depth": 100,
        "widthSegments": 1,
        "heightSegments": 1,
        "depthSegments": 1
    }],
"materials": [
    {
        "uuid": "6B15E58A-F80D-4BC4-A1DE-185A846B6BBD",
        "type": "MeshPhongMaterial",
        "color": 16777215,
        "emissive": 0,
        "specular": 1118481,
        "shininess": 30,
        "side": 2,
        "opacity": 0.5,
        "transparent": true
    },
    {
        "uuid": "BD2913CC-3A1F-45A7-8498-F90988426445",
        "type": "MeshLambertMaterial",
        "color": 16777215,
        "emissive": 16723858
    },
    {
        "uuid": "135C8BD4-895B-42C8-A72D-3FB356248D7A",
        "type": "MeshLambertMaterial",
        "color": 16777215,
        "emissive": 63744
    },
    {
        "uuid": "033485A5-CADB-4240-B01B-8EF94148626C",
        "type": "MeshLambertMaterial",
        "color": 16777215,
        "emissive": 9605120
    },
    {
        "uuid": "DD696C09-0225-446A-A040-CA9917C49D6A",
        "type": "MeshLambertMaterial",
        "color": 16777215,
        "emissive": 275455
    },
    {
        "uuid": "7E04EF43-1516-433E-ABD1-42E303AA0F19",
        "type": "MeshLambertMaterial",
        "color": 16777215,
        "emissive": 9705297
    }],
"object": {
    "uuid": "6BE54385-5498-42D2-B3D4-2377AE039F70",
    "type": "Scene",
    "name": "Scene",
    "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
    "children": [
        {
            "uuid": "C900FDBD-6DC9-41FD-8536-65AAEFD4CC13",
            "type": "Mesh",
            "name": "Box 1",
            "geometry": "0F1A7764-83AC-41AE-BB49-AE74A475CF80",
            "material": "6B15E58A-F80D-4BC4-A1DE-185A846B6BBD",
            "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-44.368385314941406,1],
            "children": [
                {
                    "uuid": "E04152A2-AA7D-4D36-AAF7-63CF6A109D42",
                    "type": "Mesh",
                    "name": "Torus 2",
                    "geometry": "E69365CA-206A-4286-BB0D-940A804B7DEB",
                    "material": "BD2913CC-3A1F-45A7-8498-F90988426445",
                    "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,16.59000015258789,0,108,1]
                },
                {
                    "uuid": "37414A51-B50E-4944-AFC5-A15EA7B0AF58",
                    "type": "Mesh",
                    "name": "Sphere 3",
                    "geometry": "B2B3E2FD-17C5-42B3-8732-0918F4196199",
                    "material": "135C8BD4-895B-42C8-A72D-3FB356248D7A",
                    "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-169.27000427246094,1]
                },
                {
                    "uuid": "6B0D91CC-C760-4311-A2BF-7A83C2E86306",
                    "type": "Mesh",
                    "name": "Cylinder 4",
                    "geometry": "CCB3F065-632D-4AD4-AB16-6DC65D3F9163",
                    "material": "033485A5-CADB-4240-B01B-8EF94148626C",
                    "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
                }]
        },
        {
            "uuid": "280B1F69-8E93-442E-A49D-42BF45004313",
            "type": "PointLight",
            "name": "PointLight 1",
            "color": 16777215,
            "intensity": 1,
            "distance": 0,
            "decay": 1,
            "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,-165.60302734375,0,-170.2801971435547,1]
        },
        {
            "uuid": "44E76258-B0C2-43B1-99FB-0BE25D31972A",
            "type": "Mesh",
            "name": "Container 1",
            "geometry": "D3905F27-8D63-447B-A4D2-D4901FAB00E2",
            "material": "DD696C09-0225-446A-A040-CA9917C49D6A",
            "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,501.0995178222656,0,-383.1794738769531,1],
            "children": [
                {
                    "uuid": "A9FE3E04-1AE7-4A13-ADAF-706CE9361109",
                    "type": "Mesh",
                    "name": "Box 1",
                    "geometry": "0F1A7764-83AC-41AE-BB49-AE74A475CF80",
                    "material": "6B15E58A-F80D-4BC4-A1DE-185A846B6BBD",
                    "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-111.47900390625,1],
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "uuid": "3C7CB934-95EF-4327-9595-52A64AE40D2D",
                            "type": "Mesh",
                            "name": "Torus 2",
                            "geometry": "E69365CA-206A-4286-BB0D-940A804B7DEB",
                            "material": "BD2913CC-3A1F-45A7-8498-F90988426445",
                            "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,16.59000015258789,0,108,1]
                        },
                        {
                            "uuid": "7B2F4D0F-D8C3-46EF-9600-EF39D9DFE590",
                            "type": "Mesh",
                            "name": "Sphere 3",
                            "geometry": "B2B3E2FD-17C5-42B3-8732-0918F4196199",
                            "material": "135C8BD4-895B-42C8-A72D-3FB356248D7A",
                            "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-169.27000427246094,1]
                        },
                        {
                            "uuid": "D6741C5F-2B08-432A-B671-11F538EC73DF",
                            "type": "Mesh",
                            "name": "Cylinder 4",
                            "geometry": "CCB3F065-632D-4AD4-AB16-6DC65D3F9163",
                            "material": "033485A5-CADB-4240-B01B-8EF94148626C",
                            "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
                        }]
                }]
        },
        {
            "uuid": "426C5B44-3DA4-4451-81B9-9CA53780411E",
            "type": "Mesh",
            "name": "Container 2",
            "geometry": "EE1DB156-C18F-41B1-B1B5-E4B2619F6FC2",
            "material": "7E04EF43-1516-433E-ABD1-42E303AA0F19",
            "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,488.5225524902344,0,548.1283569335938,1]
        }]
}
```

}

This issue has been raised in the past by [BuschnicK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360936/will-three-js-object3d-clone-create-a-deep-copy-of-the-geometry)

I repeat the question here because if I use the clone operation, this created a copy in memory of the volume and its childs. Althaugh geometries and materials are copied but only the mesh and and positioning, it created a huge memory problem.

I would like to know if there is a way to position a volume by creating only a link to that volume whithout copying in memory all the information about the volume and its childs. This would save space on disk by a factor of 500-1000 and the same savings in memory.

I would appreciate any suggestion,
Thank you in advance,
Ilias

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = Box1.children;
Box1.children = [];
var newBox = Box1.clone();
Box1.children = temp;
```

??

Comment: Answers should have more explanation than just a few lines of code.

Comment: e.g., just set the "children" array aside for a minute, clone the box, then restore the children to the original? This will mean that you get a cloned box with no kids. What's not clear to me is what the box DOES, so it's anyone's guess if this is an adequate solution.

Comment: Thank you, it looks very clever. I'll try. Cheers