# Cloning a THREE.Group hierarchy

Tags: three.js

I have a hierarchy of groups, A -> B -> C. I wish to create a clone of this hierarchy, A2 -> B2 -> C2.

But `Object3D.clone()` removes the parent reference of the group.

Other than *manually setting the parent* for each of the child-groups after cloning, what other way is there?

If the hierarchy is deep this could get take to compute.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can check out this question [Will three.js Object3D.clone() create a deep copy of the geometry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360936/will-three-js-object3d-clone-create-a-deep-copy-of-the-geometry/56665319#56665319)
I extends the `copy`and `clone` methods in `Object3D` to deep clone mesh materials.

And in your case , this should works too.

First,extends two new methods in THREE:

```
THREE.Object3D.prototype.deepClone = function ( recursive ) {

    return new this.constructor().deepCopy( this, recursive );

},
THREE.Object3D.prototype.deepCopy = function( source, recursive ) {

        if ( recursive === undefined ) recursive = true;

        this.name = source.name;

        this.up.copy( source.up );

        this.position.copy( source.position );
        this.quaternion.copy( source.quaternion );
        this.scale.copy( source.scale );

        this.matrix.copy( source.matrix );
        this.matrixWorld.copy( source.matrixWorld );
        if(source.material){
            //changed
            this.material = source.material.clone()
        }
        if(source.geometry){
            //changed
            this.geometry = source.geometry.clone()
        }
        this.matrixAutoUpdate = source.matrixAutoUpdate;
        this.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = source.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate;

        this.layers.mask = source.layers.mask;
        this.visible = source.visible;

        this.castShadow = source.castShadow;
        this.receiveShadow = source.receiveShadow;

        this.frustumCulled = source.frustumCulled;
        this.renderOrder = source.renderOrder;

        this.userData = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( source.userData ) );

        if ( recursive === true ) {

            for ( var i = 0; i < source.children.length; i ++ ) {

                var child = source.children[ i ];
                this.add( child.deepClone() ); //changed

            }

        }

        return this;

    }
```

Second,when you want to deep clone a Object3D or Scene named `originalObj`.just do `var newObj = originalObj.deepClone()`